# Disabling X-ray tracking in lambda using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

I have a bunch of lambdas that were created using terraform with X-ray tracking enabled.
now I need to disable the X-ray tracking in that lambda. It would be great if someone could help me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think we can turn it off completely.
You can play with different values for the `tracing_config` in your terraform config.

Checkout the link - [tracing_config](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function#tracing_config)

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "service" {
  # Your usual aws_lambda_function configuration settings here

  tracing_config {
    mode = "Active"
  }
}
```